# generic tree node structure: problem freeing the child nodes

Tags: delphi, generics, tree

Based on this [GenericTree](https://github.com/davidberneda/GenericTree) I have implemented the following generic tree node structure:

```pascal
type
  TTreeNode<T>=class
  private
    procedure FreeChildNodes; 
    procedure RemoveMyselfFromParentChildNodesList;
    function GetIndexInParentChildNodesList: Integer;
  public
    NodeData: T;
    ChildNodes: TList<TTreeNode<T>>;
    ParentNode: TTreeNode<T>;
    constructor Create(const AParentNode: TTreeNode<T>); overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TTreeNode<T>.Create(const AParentNode: TTreeNode<T>);
begin
  inherited Create;
  ParentNode:=AParentNode;
  ChildNodes:=TList<TTreeNode<T>>.Create;
end;

destructor TTreeNode<T>.Destroy;
begin
  FreeChildNodes;
  RemoveMyselfFromParentChildNodesList;
  ChildNodes.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTreeNode<T>.FreeChildNodes;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := ChildNodes.Count-1 downto 0 do
  begin
    ChildNodes[i].Free;
  end;
  ChildNodes.Clear;
end;

function TTreeNode<T>.GetIndexInParentChildNodesList: Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result:=-1;
  if ParentNode<>nil then
  begin
    Result:=ParentNode.ChildNodes.IndexOf(Self);
  end;
end;

procedure TTreeNode<T>.RemoveMyselfFromParentChildNodesList;
begin
  if ParentNode<>nil then
  begin
    ParentNode.ChildNodes.Delete(GetIndexInParentChildNodesList);
  end;
end;
```

This is working fine.

Now I would like to create an descendant class with a specific object type.

The object type is:

```pascal
type
  TMyObject=class
  public
    Value: string;
    constructor Create; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
```

And the new descendant class:

```pascal
type
  TMyTreeNode=class(TTreeNode<TMyObject>)
  private
  public
    constructor Create(const AParentNode: TMyTreeNode); overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMyTreeNode.Create(const AParentNode: TMyTreeNode);
begin
  inherited Create(AParentNode);
  NodeData:=TMyObject.Create;
end;

destructor TMyTreeNode.Destroy;
begin
  NodeData.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

When I free a `TMyTreeNode` with `TMyTreeNode.Destroy` the inherited `TTreeNode<T>.Destroy` is called to free the `ChildNodes` recursively. The problem is that all ChildNodes are then freed with `TTreeNode<T>.Destroy` and therefore the `TMyObjects` are **not** freed leaving a memory leak.

I also tried to use `TObjectList` instead of `TList` for the `ChildNodes`. However the `TObjectList` seems to destroy itself before I can free the child nodes.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
procedure TTreeNode<T>.FreeChildNodes;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := ChildNodes.Count-1 downto 0 do
  begin
    ChildNodes[i].NodeData.free;
    ChildNodes[i].Free;
  end;
  ChildNodes.Clear;
end;
```

There's no need to override the destructor if it only affects fields of the parent type. In your case the `TMyTreeNode.Destroy` only frees the NodeData from the parent, so you might just as well do it in the `TTreeNode<T>.FreeChildNodes` procedure.